# How to display at the same time occurrences of two different words?

Tags: helm, search, occur, icicles

Thanks to `helm-swoop`, I know how to display occurrences of a *single* word. Now, I'd like to display *at the same time* occurrences of *many* different words (of a given, single buffer).

Let me be specific: say, I have a buffer containing multiple occurrences of the two words 'Hello' and 'Bye', and I'd like to check each 'Hello' is followed by a 'Bye' before any further 'Hello'. For this, I'd like to filter *at the same time* the occurrences of these two words. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using [`helm-swoop`](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop)

#### Solution

Use `helm-swoop` to find occurrences of words `WORD1` and `WORD2` in the buffer.

```
M-x helm-swoop RET WORD1\|WORD2 RET
```

#### Old answer

Use `helm-swoop` to find occurrences of pairs of words `WORD1` and `WORD2` in the buffer, **in the same line**.

```
M-x helm-swoop RET WORD1 WORD2 RET
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason I don't understand, that doesn't work with my `GNU Emacs 24.4.1` (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.6) and an up to date `helm-swoop` (version 20150121.20), as shown by [this screenshot](http://gte.univ-littoral.fr/members/dbitouze/pub/divers/emacs/how-to-display-at-the/downloadFile/file/ehs.png). What could I check?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé the words have to be on the same line. Give it a prefix argument if you want it to cross lines. (like `C-u 4 M-x helm-swoop` to search across 4 lines.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the words are disseminated in the whole big file.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé For such cases, I use the non-helm way: `C-M-s  WORD1[[:ascii:][:nonascii:]]*?WORD2`. This does search of `WORD1` followed any *anything*, even multiple lines, followed by `WORD2`.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is not limited to Helm, you can do this in [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) using command [`icicle-occur` (bound to **`C-c '`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview)) in either of these ways, depending on what you want:

- Type the regexp `Hello.*Bye`, if you want to look for `Hello` followed by `Bye`.
- Type `Hello` then `S-SPC` then `Bye`, if you want to look for both words in either order.

`C-c '` uses lines as search contexts. Whatever you type as the dynamic text to look for in lines is matched.

The two examples above assume that you want to match both `Hello` and `Bye` in the same line. If you want to match *either* instead of both within a line, then use a pattern that matches either: `Hello\|Bye`.

Comment: Am I supposed to hit ENTER after that? In such a case, it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Please read the doc a bit. `S-TAB` shows you all of the matches. `C-down` to cycle among matches. `RET` to exit (stay at) a match.  ***"It doesn't work"*** is not particularly helpful in letting me understand your problem so that I can help you.  My advice, if you are interested, is to [**start with the doc**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview). That's why I linked to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, despite a look at the doc, I couldn't make it work. Here is my workflow: `C-c '` → Choose an occurrence: → Hello → `S-SPC` → [2] Match also (regexp): → Bye. And then, nothing happens e.g. if I hit `S-TAB` (except [No apropos completion] appears for few seconds).

Comment: Either (a) navigate to an occurrence (using `down` or `C-down`) and then hit `RET` or (b) type stuff that reduces the matches to a single match. If `S-TAB` tells you there is no match then my guess is that there is no match - no line with both `Hello` and `Bye`.  If you are expecting matches that are *not* in the same line, then use command `icicle-search` (bound to ``C-c ` ``), not `icicle-occur` (`C-c '`).

Comment: If you want to match lines that have *either* `Hello` or `Bye`, then use `C-c '` with, for example, regexp `Hello\|Bye` (use `S-TAB` to see the matches). If you want to match text within occurrences of `Hello` and `Bye` (anywhere - i.e., search only the `Hello` and `Bye` zones of text) then use ``C-c ` `` with the context-defining regexp `Hello\|Bye`. Beyond this help, please see the doc. This is not the place for a discussion or a tutorial.

Comment: OK, and in fact, the `Hello\|Bye` regexp works with `helm-swoop` as well. One of the `helm-swoop`'s advantages is that navigating from occurrence to another in the `helm-swoop` buffer, you navigate in the same time in the main buffer, and could look at the context.

Comment: "*One of the `helm-swoop`'s advantages...*" - The same is true in Icicles, using **`C-`** with the navigate keys (e.g., `C-down` vs just `down`), as I said. One advantage of having both is that you can, if you want, cycle to choose particular occurrences to visit, without needing to visit the occurrences in between. If you *want* to visit them, then just hold down the modifier key `C-` while you cycle. You can also sort the matches in various ways, so that you cycle in different orders - another advantage of showing matches both separately and in context. (All in the Icicles docs, of course.)

Comment: Indeed, Icicles also has the features I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Drew answer, I could manage to make `helm-swoop` filter at the same time the occurrences of two words (say 'Hello' and 'Bye'): `M-x helm-swoop RET Hello\|Bye`.

Comment: Great, but then change the accepted answer to one of the Helm answers (yours or kaushalmodi's which also have this solution added), so those who search for this Helm problem and find this helm-swoop question, can see the Helm answer as accepted, because that's what they are interested in, and that's what fits the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Using Occur

#### Solution

Use **Occur** to find occurrences of words `WORD1` and `WORD2` in the buffer.

```
M-x occur RET WORD1\|WORD2 RET
```

Then [use `M-g M-n` and `M-g M-p` to navigate the results from the buffer containing text](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/searching-buffers-occur-mode).

#### Old answer

Use **Occur** to find occurrences of **pairs of words** `WORD1` and `WORD2` in the buffer, which could be across multiple lines.

```
M-x occur RET WORD1[[:ascii:][:nonascii:]]*?WORD2 RET
```

[image]

*Note: Word highlighting is done using [`hl-anything`](https://github.com/boyw165/hl-anything) package, available through Melpa.*

Comment: AFAICS, this doesn't *filter* the relevant lines.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I then did not understand how you wanted the filtering to be done. First have a look at the last occurrence of `Hello` and `Bye` in the `*scratch*` buffer. Now look at last match in the `*Occur*` buffer.. you will see that it has filtered out only the line including and between the lines containing those 2 words, from line 32 to line 35. The previous occurrence of those 2 words was between lines 25-26, and so on. In all, it found 5 occurrences of `Hello ... Bye` across multiple lines.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé From your comments in the other post, I realized you need to see all occurrences of `Hello` and `Bye`, not necessarily in pairs. In that case, the same `Hello\|Bye` expression would work for Occur too. About navigating easily to all the occurrences, it is already supported out-of-the box, [use `M-g M-n` and `M-g M-p` from the buffer containing the text](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/searching-buffers-occur-mode).